# Chrome bug "Unable to parse ciphertext object!" with connect-mongo 4.6.0 for Node.js to store Express session data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-chrome, session, cryptography

In connecting my MongoDB to Node.js for storing session information by **connect-mongo v.4.6.0**, when testing my app in **Chrome** (v.106.0.5249.121), browser sends me "**Unable to parse ciphertext object!**". Instead, in Brave and Edge all works and session data are ciphered and stored correctly.
This is my MongoStore and Express session configuration:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const mongoStore = MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: urlDBLocale,
    crypto: { // this parameter causes "Unable to parse ciphertext object" in Chrome
        secret: process.env.mdbssecret,
    },
    touchAfter: 24 * 3600
});
mongoStore.on("error", err=>console.log('MongoDB Session Storage error:', err));
const sessionOptions = {
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true, 
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: 3600000 
    },
    name:  'whatever', 
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.sessionSecret,
    store: mongoStore,
    resave: false
};
app.use(session(sessionOptions));
```

While the above simply doesn't work in Chrome, no errors are given by Brave and Edge and here you can see that sessions are stored correctly in MongoDB when I try with those two browsers respectively:

```
> db.sessions.find()
{ "_id" : "tAD7alup3KP_8qzkBUkAQtgplM3QYjO_", "expires" : ISODate("2022-11-03T17:54:03.169Z"), "lastModified" : ISODate("2022-11-03T16:54:03.169Z"), "session" : "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" }
{ "_id" : "pUX3QV5yLOEImcckJdUO1jir_tkAFPXF", "expires" : ISODate("2022-11-03T17:56:28.397Z"), "lastModified" : ISODate("2022-11-03T16:56:28.398Z"), "session" : "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" }
```

What should I do? Try a previous version of connect-mongo - and if yes, which one and with what configuration in Node.js - or is there a solution to this Chrome bug?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved itself in Chrome's version 107.0.5304.88.